# Deleting values in a coloumn except first 7 values

Tags: mysql

Trying to delete values in a column except the first 7

Column combine values= "0000396Memorial Hosp of Wm F & Gertrude F Jones A/K/A Jones Memorial Hosp"

I basically need just the first 7 values = 0000396

Can anyone please guide me to the right direction?

Comment: Ugh. Can you post table structure and output of a `SELECT * from <table> LIMIT 1` or so? Figuring out your table structure from your question is very tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) string function to return the 7 leftmost characters:

```
UPDATE table SET column = LEFT(column, 7)
```

Comment: thank YOU!! I was so over thinking the whole query. I will add this to my universal scripts. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I am understanding the question correctly, you can

`UPDATE table SET column = SUBSTRING(column FROM 1 FOR 7);`